# Sorting a single dimensional array of strings

Tags: arrays, swift, string

If I have an array like this:

```
var names = ["Bob Smith", "Carl Jones", "Mike Thompson"]
```

And I wanted to sort them in alphabetical order using the second part of the string separated by the white space(so the "Smith" in "Bob Smith"), would the easiest way be to just separate the strings by white space creating two sub-strings and then comparing the two end parts, or is there a simpler way of doing it?

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Comment: There are cultures where the family name is placed first ...

Comment: Fair point, I edited my post. @MartinR

Comment: You should come up with a more sophisticated method for storing names. People can have middle names or even several family names in some countries, so simply storing full names as strings is a bad idea.

Comment: Even "western" names can be more difficult to handle correctly: ["Johann Heinrich Tischbein the Younger"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Heinrich_Tischbein_the_Younger)

Comment: Hahah ok I think I'll just create a Person class and add properties for naming and compare them that way.  I was just wondering if presented with an array like the _names_ array in the OP, if there was a simple way of grabbing the second part of the string for each name mentioned and sorting the array that way by comparing those elements, but if it's bad practice I won't try to do it.

Comment: Maybe using names as an example was a bad idea, I'm just interested splitting up the array and comparing the two parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved similar challenge by making a struct with first and last names. It was then easy to select how I wanted to sort the names.

```swift
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}

let people = [
    Person(firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith"),
    Person(firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Jones"),
    Person(firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Thompson")
]

let sorted = people.sorted { $0.lastName < $1.lastName }
```